# Worst Case minimum Sorting Time Complexity Theorem

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I am studying sorting algorithms and I am stuck on the theorem that proves that a sorting algorithm on an n vector has ,at least, in the worst case a time complexity of

n*log2(n) + (1/2)*log2(n) - log2(e)*n + O(1)

Thee proof uses a Lemma which states that a binary tree with k leafs has an height of at least ceiling(log2(n)). The theorem states that you can build a binary decision tree with n! leafs and uses the Stirling formula to get to the result! It should be a classic theorem in the field of sorting algos.

My issue is that I can't figure out how the n! leaf binary tree is build! If for example we want to sort the vector v=(4,3,1) in increasing order how can I build the decision tree with 3!=6 leafs?

I apologize for possible mistakes and for not using math formulas properly.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Is this time complexity based solely on the number of compares or does it also include the number of moves? This can be an issue, as a 4 way merge sort does 1.5 x the number of compares, but 0.5 x the number of moves of a 2 way merge.

Comment: It should be the number of comparisons since it's the minimum height of the tree shown in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building that decision tree from a sorting algorithm is easy.  Each comparison that the sorting algorithm could try divides the possible set of orders it could be into two groups.  The sorting algorithm finishes when only one possible order is left.

You literally write out your possible decisions as a tree (<, >) into (left, right).  Or up/down if you draw the tree sideways.

```
          a<b?
           |
     Y-----------N
     |           |
    b<c?        a<c?
     |           |
  Y-----N     Y-----N
  |     |     |     |
(abc)  a<c? (bac)  b<c?
        |           |
     Y-----N     Y-----N
     |     |     |     |
   (acb) (cab) (bca) (cba)
```

Now the unsolved in general question is this.  What is the best possible decision tree? :-)

Comment: Pretty clear answer! Thanks a lot... I didn't get the last question you posed since I just started studying sorting algorithms. Could you please explain it to me? The think I can imagine is that, since the theorem proves that this is the least number of computations required in the worst case, you are referring to the average case? Thanks again anyway!

Comment: @AntoninoDG The theorem gives a lower bound but doesn't say how good it is.  Analyzing any specific sorting algorithm gives you an upper bound.  The actual minimum is somewhere between those.  See https://oeis.org/A036604 for the best known answers for small numbers of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example:

```
if (v[0] <= v[1]) {
  if (v[1] <= v[2]) {
    // Sorted order: v[0], v[1], v[2]
  } else {
    // v[1] > v[2], so v[1] is a maximal element
    if (v[0] <= v[2]) {
      // Sorted order: v[0], v[2], v[1]
    } else {
      // Sorted order: v[2], v[0], v[1]
    }
  }
} else {
  // v[0] > v[1]
  if (v[1] > v[2]) {
    // Sorted order: v[2], v[1], v[0]
  } else {
    // v[1] <= v[2], so v[1] is a minimal element
    if (v[0] <= v[2]) {
      // Sorted order: v[1], v[0], v[2]
    } else {
      // Sorted order: v[1], v[2], v[0]
    }
  }
}
```

This decision tree has 6 leafs and it takes at most 3 decisions to reach the leaf.

And in general, how you actually build a decision tree is called "sorting algorithm". If you run an algorithm on all possible inputs, you can track how it makes decision about swapping elements and build corresponding decision tree.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and made me think!Thanks for your answer! Greetings